# How to trigger an external url redirect onformsubmitted

Tags: html, hubspot

Anyone know how to trigger an external URL redirect onFormSubmitted?

I'm playing with custom code for a hubspot form, and previously i've used the code below which would redirect me to an internally linked page, but I can't seem to find code that would redirect to an external page.

For example, I want my on-demand webinar Hubspot form to redirect to the webinar recording which is hosted on vimeo - so i'd need to add the vimeo link

```
    onFormSubmitted: function($form) {
        window.location.replace("/thankyou"); // optional redirect
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have it almost right (it's actually the same code, but I don't think the onFormSubmitted has $form as a parameter, which is the case with onFormSubmit):

```
onFormSubmitted: function() {
    window.location.href="the-vimeo-link";
}
```